# How to add a CMake custom target to test all sub-projects?

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have a repository with several projects inside. The resulting directory structure is like this :

```
Repository
  --CMakeLists.txt
  --Project A
      --CMakeLists.txt
  --Project B
      --CMakeLists.txt
```

In projects A and B I have tests that I add using `add_test`. When inside a project I can do `make test`.

How can I add a target "test" to the top CMakeLists.txt to be able to call `make test` from the top directory and get the tests of all projects executed ?

Comment: Are you using `add_subdirectory` in your top-level `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: @pmr Yes I do use it.

Comment: So, technically `make test` should already do what you want. What could go wrong is that you call `enable_testing` only in the subprojects but not in the upper layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just tried to reproduce your setup with the following files:

```
/tmp/test $ tree
.
├── a
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── b
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── CMakeLists.txt

/tmp/test $ cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(Foo)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(a)
add_subdirectory(b)
/tmp/test $ cat a/CMakeLists.txt 
project(A)
add_test(NAME atest COMMAND echo "hello from a")
/tmp/test $ cat b/CMakeLists.txt 
project(B)
add_test(NAME btest COMMAND echo "hello from b")

/tmp/test/build $ mkdir build && cd build
/tmp/test/build $ cmake .. && make test
# Remove some output
Running tests...
Test project /tmp/test/build
    Start 1: atest
1/2 Test #1: atest ............................   Passed    0.00 sec
    Start 2: btest
2/2 Test #2: btest ............................   Passed    0.00 sec
```

Comment: I had the "enable_testing()" in both subprojects but not in the top CMakeLists.txt. Once I put it there, it worked as expected. Thank you.